# Sharing projects (Services) between Universal Apps and ASP.NET 5.0

Tags: asp.net, dll, win-universal-app

I am creating a Universal App (Windows 10) and separated the Model/ViewModel into a separate Universal Windows DLL.

When I create a ASP.NET 5.0 web site in the future will I be able to add that project and use it from ASP.NET 5.0 ?  Or do I need to convert it to a portable library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create a ASP.NET 5.0 web site in the future will I be able to
>   add that project and use it from ASP.NET 5.0 ?

No, you can’t reference a UWP .NET library in ASP.NET 5.0 Project. ASP.NET 5 is based on Full .NET or ASP.NET Core, but UWP .NET project is based on UWP for .NET.

> Or do I need to convert it to a portable library ?

Technically, it should work if we create a portable library and select UWP and ASP.NET 5 Core. But there are a lot of errors when I building the ASP.NET project after referencing the portable library. My current workaround is “code share”, I put the common code (domain model classes) in a folder named “share_code” and add existing file in UWP and APS.NET project.

Comment: Ok. I can refactor it into a portable class in the future when that day comes.. But what are the errors you speak of ?